# Populate datagridview by selecting any table from combo box

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have used the following code for displaying names of my SQL db tables in combobox. Now I want when I click on any of these table names from combo box that my DataGridView populates with that table's contents.

I have three tables in my database.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        try
        {

            con.Open();

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

            sqlCmd.Connection = con;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select table_name from information_schema.tables";

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

            DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
            comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void PopulateGridView(string tablename)
    {
        String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        try
        {

            con.Open();

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

            sqlCmd.Connection = con;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from " + tablename;

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

            DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            PopulateGridView(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

}

Here is my table (datejoin)

```
rahul   sharma  12-1-2011
suresh  chand   23-4-2012
prachi  shukla  13-2-2011
siddharth   malhotra    25-9-2012
saina   chopra  12-8-2011
amit    mehta   20-3-2012
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: the question is wat will be the code for populating my dgv with the contents of table i select from combo box

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the combobox's `SelectedIndexChanged` event and retrieve the selected table name from the combobox. From there, run a query to retrieve the records from the table and bind the result to the datagridview.

Sample:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    con.Open();

    string tableName = comboBox1.SelectedText;

    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCmd.Connection = con;
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from " + tableName;

    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

    DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
    sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
    dgv.DataSource = dtRecord;
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: thanks..:) but plz can u write the code..im new to c#..plz plz plz if psb

Comment: See my edit. Also, you might want to separate your datalayer by creating different classes for retrieving records from the database.

Comment: it is showing an error on sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);....Incorrect syntax near 'from'.

Comment: Make sure you select a combobox item that is not blank. It probably throws that syntax because the selected item from the combobox is blank.

Answer (score 1):

You will have a event on combobox SelectedIndexChange and pass name of table to your function

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   RebindGridView(ComboBox1.SelectedValue);
}
```

Then in your function:

```
private void RebindGridView(string tablename)
{
  String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
            try
            {

                con.Open();

                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

                sqlCmd.Connection = con;
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from " + tablename;

                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

                DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
                sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
                gridview1.DataSource = dtRecords;
                 gridview1.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
}
```

Comment: what error do you get? also see my edit forgot space between from and tablename...it is correct now.

Comment: where do i need to define databind() ?

Comment: DataBind() is gridview's method you dont need to define it..after assigning datasource you need to bind it... see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx

Comment: sorry but i still don't get it..im not good in  programming..plz help

Comment: sorry the correct error description is this- 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: ok remove the databind() line and try and see if the gridview gets populated

Comment: no it's not...it showing a dialog box..invalid object system.data.datarowview

Comment: that might be because of your data structure... send me a sample of your code and will try to create a small project for you

Comment: well i can't post the whole code in one go...im posting it in comments in bits...

Comment: edit your question and post the code and your table data as well

Comment: can you post a sample of your database table as well

Comment: yes plz i will add the table in code above in a moment..thnks for helping this far:)

Comment: i have posted a sample of my table in the ques..plz check